# how do I create search in sharepoint list edit form using infopath

Tags: list, infopath, search, lookup-column, filter

I have a list called Tasks in sharepoint 2013 that has a number of lookup fields. It was initially created by exporting data,tables and relationships from Access 2013. The client  wants to be able to filter the search results by using the lookup fields as filters.  I believe there are 7 filters.

My question is how do i do this in infopath 2013? I think I edit an existing sharepoint form and create these filters in Infopath but have no clue how to do this. I have found an answer to this on your site but the explanation was not detailed enough for an Infopath Neophyte like myself. 
Also, if there is more than one record related to the search, how are they displayed? How is the results page created or is it just displayed like the current list search results.

I hope this makes sense and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Luis

Comment: Hi Luis, and welcome to SP.SE! Could you provide a link to the question you mentioned?